# Error: Cannot import 'account'. Check that 'accounts.apps.AccountConfig.name' is correct

Tags: python, django

When I run python manage.py runserver in Django, I get the following error.

**Error**

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'account'. Check that 'accounts.apps.AccountConfig.name' is correct.
```

I tried everything but could not figure it out.

What should I do?

**acconuts/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'account'
```

**mysite/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'app',
    'accounts',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]
```

Comment: `name = 'account'`  I think this is supposed to be `accounts`.  The module directory is `accounts`, and the installed app name is also `accounts`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error message says `Check that 'accounts.apps.AccountConfig.name' is correct`. **Did you try to do that?** Specifically - `accounts.apps.AccountConfig.name` should mean, the `name` value inside the `AccountConfig` class, inside the `apps` module, inside the `accounts` package. Right? So. What does it say in that code? The code says `name = 'account'`, right? So, that's the value for `accounts.apps.AccountConfig.name`. So. **Is that what it should be**? What do you think it should be, and why? Did you try to read documentation, or follow a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `account` your app is named `accounts`. Also, you shared file **acconuts/apps.py** - is that also your mispell?

```
class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
    name = 'accounts'   # it has to be exactly as your app name
```